# Identity Server: Add claims to ClaimPrincipal with hybrid flow in MVC client

Tags: .net, .net-core, identityserver4

I am setting up an identity server and are having trouble understanding why I cannot access a newly added claim from my MVC site.

I am using the quickstart sample no 5: ([Link on github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess)) with the following changes in the identity server:

```
public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            **new IdentityResource
            {
                Name = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                DisplayName = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                UserClaims = { JwtClaimTypes.Role }
            }**
        };
    }

public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        // client credentials client
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientName = "MVC Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets = 
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes = 
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1",
                    **JwtClaimTypes.Role**
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
        };
    }

public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "alice",
                Password = "password",

                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("name", "Alice"),
                    new Claim("website", "https://alice.com"),
                    **new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")**
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And with the following change in the mvc project

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("api1");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                **options.Scope.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);**
            });
```

Yet I am not seeing the role claim in the claims on the ClaimsPrincipal in the MVC app. I am sure there is something Im missing. I can add the claim to my accesstoken and find it in the there. I also tried to implement a ProfileService to add the claim there but still could not find it in the ClaimsPrincipal after a log in. Please enlighten me =)

My profile service:

```
 public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var user = Config.GetUsers().First();
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
            };

            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

Comment: as I understand it, the claims stored in the access token, are for the API and shouldn't be shown on the Client. I might be wrong but the claims you will see on the client are the ones in your id token.

Comment: @AntonToshik An access token is given for the Api:s - I decoded it manually using jwt.io

Comment: you are missing 2 scopes `options.Scope.Add("openid");` and
`options.Scope.Add("profile");` in your mvc app

Comment: @wheeler I think does are added by default. I added them manually now but it didnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found an answer in this thread https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1449

In short: In .net core 2.0, to avoid cookie bloat, you have to map the claims manually using a claims action.

The fix looks like this:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Scope.Add("api1");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            **options.Scope.Add(JwtClaimTypes.Role);**
            **options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Role);**
        });
```